# Save printer drivers locally in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I am making an image using Sysprep for windows 7 64 bit. I want to save printer drivers for commonly used printers. Can I just place them here `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository`? I want to be able to have Windows use those drivers when I configure the PC instead of having to tell windows where the printer drivers are.

Comment: Are you using sysprep or other image building software? What is it?

Comment: yes using sysprep

Answer (score 1):

Printers have to be installed or they will not be usable. Installation includes setting up a port for the printer, and making several changes in the registry, so just dropping in some files won't cut it.

Nearly every printer can be installed via Add Printer in Devices & Printers, as long as you have the driver files. The best thing you can do is to install the driver files somewhere on the PC and then run [RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php) from a batch file to install the printer.